# How can identify potential malware from the list of sessions established between my PC with devices on the internet

Tags: malware, detection

I wish to know if there are any software tool(s) that allow me see all established sessions from my PC and flag those connections that are potentially malware.

I prefer GUI type tool but will also consider CLI utilities

Comment: 1) Product recommendations are off-topic on Sec.SE. 2) Look into [Windows Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/).